# Crack the $4$-letter word from the following figure

Tags: cipher

[image]

As said in the title, it's a $4$-letter word. I actually found this in my old notebook which I kept like two years ago. Most likely I made this once for my friends to decipher, though I don't clearly think they ever got that and we just most likely forgot about it. So, just wanted to see, if anybody can give it a shot and get it.

Hint 1:

> To decipher this, you should just get two different concepts behind this which make 50-50 of the decryption. As you can see in figure those two contrasting parts are sure different, one must get the  "triangle" part and then move on, instead of just pondering over one thing.

Hint 2:

> No complicated math-related or pop-culture reference is involved in the process, mostly picture/shape-based. Also it is number-alphabet relation based

Comment: Mighty fine handwriting you got there :P

Comment: Did you type up the figure in LaTeX, screenshot the pdf, then cut it out of paint and upload the image?

Comment: I did it using powerpoint, much simpler for these type of things

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I was working on doing [cyclic permutations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR6EN.png) on the letters.

Comment: The fact that you found this on your old notebook is relevant?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, not at all in decrypting this, just added that as a backstory kind of thing.

Comment: I think 4 letters is too short word. Just got "Thor", but it feels random.

Comment: @Jav Ivan, I've to say, that is correct. Post it as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First step:

> Count lines in letters - "I" for 1, "V" for 2, "N" for 3, "W" for 4

Second step:

> Take numbers like: (34)(12)(24)(32) and as "base 5" transform it to 19,7,14,17

Which is one off to (or when A=0, Z=25):

> THOR